# How do I translate a polynomial with C programming without exponent operators?

Tags: c, operators, polynomial-math

I was looking in my C textbook and inside there was a page where the prompt told me to translate a polynomial into C code. We have not discussed exponent operators yet and are specifically instructed not to use them at this point and find another way with basic operators. The polynomial goes as such: `5x^(2)+3x-2`.

How do I do this?

Comment: C doesn't have an exponent operator.  You have to do repeated multiplication.

Comment: Exactly. And don't listen to those who suggest the pow() function. For simple small-integer degree polynomials, just use ` x\*x`, `x\*x\*x`, etc.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker In fact the `pow` function seems expressly forbidden by this exercise, which asks for the exponentiation to be achieved through basic operators

Comment: Even a more complex expression does not always need a power or a factorial function, such as a Maclaurin series, where each term can be based on the previous term and summed to the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an `exponent operator` in C. While you can accomplish the same thing using `pow()`. I suspect your book does not want this. Given this limitation you can do the operation of `x^2` as simply `x * x` where `x` is a variable for your function.

i.e. You can do something like this:

```
int poly(int x) {
    int y = ((5 * x * x) + (3 * x) - 2);
    return y;
}
```

Addendum:

If you want to have a general formula that you can easily extend for any polynomial degree, you can use this formula instead, with inputs for `a`, `b`, `c` and `x`:

```
int poly(int a, int b, int c, int x) {
    int y = c + x*(b + x*(a));
    return y;
}
```

Thanks to chux and FredK for this.

Comment: `((5 * x * x) + (3 * x) - 2)` is mathematically the same as `c + x*(b + x*(a))`, yet the 2nd one is more numerically stable  (less rounding error.) - often less code too.

Comment: @chux I'll note that.

Answer (score 5):

Note that `ax^2 + bx + c` can be written as

```
c + x*(b + x*(a))
```

This can easily be extended to any order of polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should parameter a,b,c and x in the second polynomial function

```
int poly2(int a, int b, int c, int x)
{
    int y = a*x*x+b*x+c;
    return y; 
}
```

when using this function for your case you can call

```
int result = poly2(a,b,c, x)
```

with a specific set of a,b,c,x

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have an exponent operator.

One really handy way to model polynomials is to use an array to store the coefficients, such that the array index corresponds to the power of `x`.  IOW, to model `5x2 + 3x - 2`, use

```
double coef[] = {-2.0, 3.0, 5.0}; // -2.0 + 3.0x + 5.0x^2
```

To evaluate the polynomial, use a loop, taking into account the property that FredK mentions in his answer - `5x2 + 3x - 2 == ((5)x + 3)x - 2`:

```
size_t num_elements = sizeof coef / sizeof coef[0]; // yields 3 in this case
double result = 0;
for (size_t i = num_elements - 1; i > 0; i--)
  result += x * ( result + coef[i] );
result += coef[0];
```

This method will work for polynomials of any degree.